# Asp.net MVC Routing not matching some file extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am having trouble with routes not matching when the contain certain file extensions in them. I suspect it might be an IIS problem but I can't seem to track it down.

First off, I have RouteExistingFiles turned off:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
```

And then I have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "category/{category}.aspx", new { controller = "Category", action = "View" });
```

and the following url does not match this route:

```
http://mysite/category/test.aspx
```

But, if I remove the file extension and cange the route to:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "category/{category}", new { controller = "Category", action = "View" });
```

Then the above url matches with {category} being set to "test.aspx"

I also have the same problem with this route:

```
routes.MapRoute("sitemap", "sitemap.xml", new { controller = "Resource", action = "Sitemap" });
```

The strange thing is that I am not having this problem with all routes with file extensions. The following routes seem to be working just fine for me:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "favicon.ico", new { controller = "Resource", action = "Favicon" });
routes.MapRoute("", "min.css", new { controller = "Resource", action = "Css" });
routes.MapRoute("", "min.js", new { controller = "Resource", action = "JavaScript" });
routes.MapRoute("", "rsd.xml", new { controller = "MetaWeblog", action = "Rsd" });
```

Is there something I should be aware of with the .aspx and .xml extensions? Could this be an IIS Problem? Is there a better way to debug this than just using [RouteDebugger](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger)?

Comment: The aspx routes you have created are working in my box with the app running in IIS 7

Comment: I have a similar issue and wondering if you found a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Is your problem is the request is not being directed to those actions if the url contains .xml or .aspx?

then I guess this should be true,

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

**UPDATE:**

I tested in two scenarios with the following route for a site running in IIS 7.

```
routes.MapRoute("sitemap", "{sitemap}.xml", 
                   new { controller = "Resource", action = "Sitemap" });
```

With `RouteExistingFiles` is false,

In this case when the sitemap.xml file is there then the request is directed to that file else the request is directed to the action.

With `RouteExistingFiles` is true,

When the sitemap.xml file exists or not all the time the request is being directed to the action.

Comment: The files being matched in the urls do not exist on disk so they do not qualify as existing files. I want these paths routed to controller actions, not serve up static files.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. For me, routing was not being invoked for files that don't have managed handlers. The following configuration worked for me:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```